Mapping Element of List into string element in Azure AI Search
I am using Azure AI Search and want to map the list output from my custom skill to an index element after having used the AzureOpenAI Skill.
E.g. I have an output from my custom skill where I chunk my text which looks like this
{ 
"values": 
      [ 
       { "recordId": "0", 
         "data": { 
                  "identifier": [ [1,2], [1,2] ], 
                  "text": ["Hello", "world"], 
                  "pagenumber": [1,2]}
                 }
       }
      ]
 }

How can I map the values from the data into scalars for my index?
The output for the example above should look like this
{
    { 
      "id: "0", 
      "identifier": [1,2], 
      "text": "Hello", 
      "embedding": [0.2, 0.3], 
      "pagenumber": 1
    },
    {
      "id: "1",
      "identifier": [1,2],
      "text": "World",
      "embedding": [0.3, 0.3],
      "pagenumber": 2

    }
}

I tried out the indexProjections in the Skillset, but I cannot map the list into scalars.


I tried out the indexProjections in the Skillset, but I cannot map the list into scalars.

Use the “outputFieldMappings” property in the skillset definition. This allows you to transform the output of one skill into the input expected by another skill or directly into the index.
Skillset:
{
  "name": "Test_set",
  "description": "skillset_description",
  "skills": [
    {
      "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Skills.Text.AzureOpenTypeSkill",
      "name": "your-azure-open-ai-skill",
      "description": "Your AzureOpenAI Skill description",
      "context": "/document",
      "inputs": [
        {
          "name": "text",
          "source": "/document/content"
        }
      ],
      "outputs": [
        {
          "name": "identifier",
          "targetName": "identifier"
        },
        {
          "name": "text",
          "targetName": "text"
        },
        {
          "name": "pagenumber",
          "targetName": "pagenumber"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Skills.Text.SentimentSkill",
      "name": "your-sentiment-skill",
      "description": "Your Sentiment Skill description",
      "inputs": [
        {
          "name": "text",
          "source": "/document/text"
        }
      ],
      "outputs": [
        {
          "name": "score",
          "targetName": "sentimentScore"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "cognitiveServices": {
    "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.CognitiveServicesByKey",
    "description": "Your cognitive services key",
    "key": "your-cognitive-services-key"
  },
  "knowledgeStore": {
    "storageConnectionString": "Your storage connection string",
    "projections": [],
    "tables": []
  },
  "skills": [],
  "outputFieldMappings": [
    {
      "sourceFieldName": "/document/identifier",
      "targetFieldName": "identifier"
    },
    {
      "sourceFieldName": "/document/text",
      "targetFieldName": "text"
    },
    {
      "sourceFieldName": "/document/pagenumber",
      "targetFieldName": "pagenumber"
    }
  ]
}

Here, Iam using both the AzureOpenAI skill and the Sentiment Analysis skill. The outputFieldMappings section specifies how the output from the skills should be mapped to fields in your index.

The outputFieldMapping for the “entities” field and include a mappingFunction called “parseJsonArray”. This function will parse the JSON array contained in the “entities” field into individual records.

Output after processing through my sample skillset and indexing into Azure AI Search.
[
  {
    "id": "0",
    "identifier": [1, 2],
    "text": "Hello",
    "pagenumber": 1,
    "embedding": [0.2, 0.3]
  },
  {
    "id": "1",
    "identifier": [1, 2],
    "text": "world",
    "pagenumber": 2,
    "embedding": [0.2, 0.3]
  }
]

Skillset Definition:


Thanks for your answer. But outputFieldMapping cannot be used in the skillset. I got the following error: "The request is invalid. Details: Cannot find nested property 'outputFieldMappings' on the resource type 'Microsoft.Azure.Search.V2024_03_01_Preview.Skillset'."

@liho You can achieve the desired mapping by using a custom skill to transform the output before indexing, ensuring each list element is appropriately mapped to the index fields.
